# Ajax binding vs Server binding

Tags: ajax, binding

I have a project which is MVC. In it, I use the telerik grid. I need to choose whether I will user server or ajax binding. What is the difference between these two?

I was told that when I pass data from the controller to the view via model, that is server binding. Is this true? If yes, how else to pass data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server binding will refresh the page every time where the Ajax one will be done on the browser with no page reloading. At least that is the difference from the user's prospective.

Ajax binding will need an extra method (the examples on the Telerik website are using " _AjaxBinding()"). That method is called in the grid .ajax() located in the view.

And yes, A normal call is server binding.