# difference between Kendo DropDownList for server binding and ajax binding using kendoUI

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/dropdownlist/overview

difference between Kendo DropDownList for server binding and ajax binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see for example this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542545/1127669.

Basically, server binding will refresh the whole page every time an action changes the list whether the ajax binding sends an ajax request which only changes the dropdownlist...

Comment: what is advantage of server binding over ajax binding?

Comment: @niccky the advantage of the server binding is this is easier to code :-) and the potential other advantage and that when you load the page, the data are already present in the DDL! In the ajax case, it is another request to the server and you have to wait for its completion before using the DDL. The 2 are really 2 different approaches : the first one : all data is loaded with the page (no need to wait for using the DDL), the second : the rest of the page is loaded faster and you can change the DDL without reloading the whole page...